# Sigma Summation function in Excel - Aritmetical Gradients

Tags: excel, gradient

I want to write a formula in Excel that works as follow:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhFXE.png]

Where:

> ```
> G = Aritmetical Gradient value 
> R = Rent value
> i = Interest Rate value (expressed in %)
> n = Numbers of months
> ```

Any help you can give me, I will be really thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMPRODUCT will do this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2+B1*(B4-SEQUENCE(B4+1,,0)))*(1+B3)^SEQUENCE(B4+1,,0))
```

I made the assumption you want to include where k=n if not then remove the `+1`s in the formula.

[image]

---

If one does not have SEQUENCE we can substitute `(ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B4+1))-1)`

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2+B1*(B4-(ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B4+1))-1)))*(1+B3)^(ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B4+1))-1))
```

[image]